# How to insert a code in a blade view dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Using laravel 5.1, could I insert a custom code into a blade view dynamically?
For example, I have this `view.blade.php` :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    @section('sidebar')
        This is the master sidebar.
    @show

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
        // Here, I want to insert a code dynamically, for example :
        <div> <p> something </p> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So, Is there a good way to do something like this in controller :

```
$customCode = "<div> <p> something </p> </div>";
$content = (string) $view;
//For example I want to insert this code into view file on line 11
updateContent($content, $customCode, $line_position_in_view);
```

Comment: Do you want to print a variable there ?

Comment: No, a custom code : html, javascript, php ,... whatever

Comment: you ques is not clear to me.

Comment: I mean how could I edit a file code dynamically, blade view for example

Comment: @BKF Why dont you use jquery for that.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer please could you give me an example ?

Comment: do you want to call the function in blade ?

Comment: Sorry, may be my question is not clear ... 
what I realy want : how can I edit the current blade view code by adding a custom code in line position 11 for example, and then the file will updated

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: transform your view.blade.php into a layout and create another section where you want your new content to appear, then override it in the view that extends the layout

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code with jQuery :

Your HTML FILE OR VIEW FILE

```
<div class="container">
        @yield('content')
        // Here, I want insert a code dynamically, for example :
        <div> <p> something </p> </div>
    </div>

$.post("test.php",{},function (data){
     $(".container").append(data);
});
```

Note : if you want to use controller function then change `test.php` with function name with proper path.

test.php file or controller function

```
<?php
echo "<div> <p> something </p> </div>";
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For instance let's say you don't want to insert something like

```
 {{$user->name}}
```

but more styled html chunk of code instead with the same string showed,
say by bootstrap 4. then you have to assign to the name a string like

```
$user->update(['name' => '<span class="badge badge-success">SHILPILDOQ</span>']);
```

**AND FINALLY** for the blade file you have a little change now :

```
{!! $user->name !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not suppose to just put html and javascript in your controller so you can dump it out into your blade view. This goes against the seperation of concerns.

You should just create a master layout and extend this master layout on other pages you create. This way you can dynamically adjust the content of the master layout page.

Naturally, you should never ever mix php functions into your blade view. Run the php functionality in your controller, put it into a variable and pass it along to your view to use.

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm speaking about dynamic file code edition, for example I have a page contains two buttons, is it a good idea to access to the page code via a modal for example and make one button hidden ? I don't want to go back to the holy project code using php editor to do this edit ,,, hope my idea is clear